# Add button on top of grid control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid control as the main content area of my application. What I want is a tab-style button at the bottom center of the application window which floats on top of the grid and retains its position centered in the parent window even when you scroll the grid. The use of this is that I have a lower drawer that I want the user to be able to expand upwards on demand and collapse it again - but they need the little tab always there, docked to the bottom of the window so they can click it to open up the drawer.

How can I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `DataGrid` and the `Button` in the same `Grid`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg">
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This should make the `Button` always appear at the bottom center and on top of the `DataGrid`:

[image]